# Sorting results by relevance

Tags: mysql

I'm working on an internal search engine for my website. I have an "advanced search" with around 20 criteria, and I would like to sort the results by relevance : the entries meeting the highest number of criteria should show up first. After doing some research, I found that the "CASE WHEN" syntax would be useful, but I'm not sure if I'm using it well. Now I have something like :

```
select
case when name like "%test%" then 1 else 0 +
case when lastname like "%test%" then 1 else 0 end as nb_criteria
from MyTable1, MyTable2....
```

This works fine. My first column is "nb_criteria" and I just have to order the results accordingly. The problem with that is it just reorders all the entries of my database, so the less relevant results have a value of "0", but they are still there. Therefore I have to use a WHERE statement, which I think would make the server performs the same task twice.

What is the best way to achieve this?

Thanks

Comment: Yes, you will have to repeat that calculation, if you want to get the value returned and use it in a WHERE clause; you can not use a column alias to refer to the it in the WHERE clause. The alternative would be HAVING instead of WHERE - but that can cause bad performance, because that means that in a first step _all_ records will be select, and only afterwards those not matching the condition will be sorted out.

Comment: @CBroe Correct me if I'm wrong, but how could a HAVING have a worse impact on performance than a WHERE statement? As I said, there could be up to 20 criteria, so wouldn't using a HAVING be a better choice than having 20 CASE's then 20 WHERE's?

Comment: It's mainly about memory consumption. Using WHERE, the database looks at each record one at a time, if it fits the criteria it is added to the result set that is build up in RAM. No match, throw record away, check the next one. HAVING only works _after_ the result set is built up in RAM, meaning if you do the filtering only then, you have the _whole_ table content stuffed into RAM, and only then the non-matching records get filtered out from there.

Comment: Repeating the calculation in the WHERE clause is not as bad as it might look at first glance. The database has the means to recognize and optimize this internally.

Comment: @CBroe Thank you. Then I'm looking forward to try this. Feel free to leave an "official" answer